# Is there a more efficient alternative to nesting an if statement within a for loop in C# when dealing with large numbers of iterations?

Tags: c#, nested-loops, coding-efficiency

I have a method which consists of an if statement nested within a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < val; i=i+2)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < val; j=j+1)
    {
        actualDistance = actualDistance + (ulong)Math.Max(revenue[i], revenue[j]) * (ulong)Math.Abs(point[j] - point[i]);

        if (j + 1 < val)
        {
            actualDistance = actualDistance + (ulong)Math.Max(revenue[i+1], revenue[j+1]) * (ulong)Math.Abs(point[j+1] - point[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if val represents a number within the tens of millions, then the method takes a very long time during runtime since it is used in both the for and if loops.

Is there a better and more efficient way of doing this? The code as it currently stands is too time inefficient.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop" -- `if` statements don't loop. As it stands, your question doesn't show any nested loops at all.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `while (j + 1 < val)` to make it *nested loop*. But still when the values reach high in form of millions then you need to have a better CPU not a better code.

Comment: @DanielPryden: My bad, I worded my question poorly. I meant an if statement, not an if loop.

Comment: I'm sure your If condition is always satisfied. No point testing a condition when its always true.

Comment: This looks like it could be run in parallel; in which case it is ideal circumstance for offloading the calculations to the GPU. I suggest you check that out.

Comment: @AnupSharma There is one case when it's not: when `j == val - 1`.

Comment: @benlisquare: Aside from eliding the if check entirely, there's nothing else here that would make a substantial difference in the runtime. If you need to loop over all the elements, then that's `O(n)` and you're not going to get any more efficient than that (asymptotically speaking).  The best way to optimize this kind of code is to attack the problem differently: do you care more about total CPU time, or simply user-visible latency? If the latter, perhaps a parallel algorithm is what you're looking for.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes my bad. I overlook it. But I agree, Task.Parallel should be used for this loop. That will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Either I'm missing something or your code is equivalent to:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < val; j=j+1)
{
    actualDistance = actualDistance + (ulong)Math.Max(revenue[i], revenue[j]) * (ulong)Math.Abs(point[j] - point[i]);

    actualDistance = actualDistance + (ulong)Math.Max(revenue[i+1], revenue[j+1]) * (ulong)Math.Abs(point[j+1] - point[i+1]);
}

actualDistance = actualDistance - (ulong)Math.Max(revenue[i+1], revenue[val]) * (ulong)Math.Abs(point[val] - point[i+1])
```

Your `if` statement will be almost always true and the only case when it's false is when `j == val - 1`, so you can just always run the code inside `if` statement and than subtract that last case outside of `for` loop.